# JLabel1 Horizontal text alignment not working

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am currently trying to make a GUI Application. I am trying to get the text in the jLabels to align to the right but it does not work even though I have it selected in Netbeans. Is there a reason why it isn't working? I have attached a picture showing the scenario

[Picture of the GUI Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUgzB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalTextPosition-int-)

> **setHorizontalTextPosition**
>
> ```
> public void setHorizontalTextPosition(int textPosition)
> ```
>
> Sets the horizontal position of the label's text, **relative to its image.**

*Emphasis applied by me*

This means that the text will placed to the desired position relative to the labels icon image.

Instead, what I think you're after is [`JLabel#setHorizontalAlignment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalAlignment-int-)

> setHorizontalAlignment
>
> ```
> public void
> setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment)
> ```
>
> Sets the alignment of
>   the label's contents along the X axis.

Rather then just plugging away at properties, make sure you're consulting the JavaDocs to make sure the property is performing the functionality you want.  Also, don't forget to refer to other examples or tutorials, like [How to use labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) when ever you get stuck